# sticky table not working with different sized windows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap-4 for the table.I've used this css styling to make my header and the first column sticky.
https://css-tricks.com/a-table-with-both-a-sticky-header-and-a-sticky-first-column/
here's the link to the code and problem

https://js-zav1u3.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zav1u3?file=index.html

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zav1u3?file=style.css

It seems to be working fine on desktop but when the mobile view in the chrome developer tools is used, it doesn't work. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Can't reproduce, Can you provide a working snippet illustrating the issue ?

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] as a snippet in the question body.  As @ZohirSalak mentions, this will allow the community to see the issue reproduced right here on the page, better understand the issue, and enable us to copy that snippet into an answer to assist you.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I've added the stackblitz link. you can checkout the problem there by viewing the output in the mobile view using chrome developer tool

Comment: This selector `[role='region'][aria-labelledby][tabindex]` isn't selecting anything, and it should target `.row` in your example, Basically the parent of the table whatever that might be. There seems to be some quirkiness with the mobile view, if you to see it add `body,html{overflow:scroll}` the body and html will generate separate stacking context and the sticky behavior won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code

```
table thead tr th{
         position: -webkit-sticky;
         position: sticky;
         top: 0;
    }
```

You can add background color to hide other data

Comment: that's not working in the mobile view either

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to set overflow to scroll and a height to your row containers. This allows you to scroll with sticky headers on mobile.

```
<div class="row" style="overflow: scroll; height: 600px;">
    ...
</div>
```